# How to move Canvas Shape with timer

Tags: android, canvas, timer

My Circle Class !!

```
public class Circle extends View{
int y =0 ;


public line(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
protected void  onDraw(Canvas c){
    super.onDraw(c);
    Paint p=new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    p.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    p.setStrokeWidth(3);

    if (y==0){
        c.drawCircle(100,y+5,50,p);
    }
    else{
        c.drawCircle(100,y+5,50,p);
    }
}
public void invalidate(){
    invalidate();
}
```

And MainActivity!!

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    RelativeLayout rl=new RelativeLayout(this);
    setContentView(rl);
    rl.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    Circle c=new Circle(this);
    rl.addView(c);
    Timer t=new Timer();//here is Where I need help
    t.schedule(new MyNewTimer(),0,20);//here is Where I need help
    }



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

I got timer idea from some websites. I am beginner of android programming. I really don't know how to move this shape with timer. Actually, I have no idea where to put this timertask and where to put moving ! 
kindly help me please !!

I add this on onCreate()

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new MyTimer(),0,20);
```

I Create MyTimer class

```
public class MyTimer extends TimerTask{
@Override
public void run(){
    handler.post(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            //Here, I can't inherit circle.invalidate() 
        }
    }};

}
```

Comment: Your `onDraw` method for `Circle` has an `if` statement that draws the same thing regardless of the value of `y`; you should explain what you're trying to accomplish. Also, your `invalidate()` method will recurse until the stack overflows. Finally, you need to tell us what the `MyNewTimer` class does.

Comment: yess, yess . I created MyNewTimer class earlier but I can't inherit y from circle class. MyNewTimer need invalidate() to be static but by changing this ,there is an error in circle class .I've no idea to fix it. Please give me advice to meet the right fix! thank you so much Ted Hopp !!

Comment: I Add this on onCreate()

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new MyTimer(),0,20);

And create class MyTimer
    public class MyTimer extends TimerTask{
  @Override
 public void run(){
  handler.post(new Runnable(){
   public void run(){
    //I cant call invalidate() , how to call it ?
   }
  }};

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a background thread, you need to call `postInvalidate()` for a `View` rather than `invalidate()` (which must be called on the UI thread). You can probably do something like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        RelativeLayout rl=new RelativeLayout(this);
        setContentView(rl);
        rl.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        final Circle c = new Circle(this);
        rl.addView(c);
        Timer t=new Timer();
        TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // update the y coordinate in c
                . . .
                // ask for the view to be redrawn
                c.postInvalidate();
            }
        };
        t.schedule(task, 0, 20);
    }
}
```

Note that `c` must be declared `final` in this code so that it can be referenced from the anonymous `TimerTask` object. If you create a separate class (such as `MyNewTimer`), then you could pass a reference to `c` in the constructor so it has access to the view.

As I pointed out in my comment, you have other problems with `Circle`. I'd start by eliminating the `invalidate` method that you wrote.

Comment: Your code is successfully helpful ! Thank you so xo much for giving your time and sharing knowledge ! My circle is now moving !! :) Thankss !